# Dealing with equal numbers in usort PHP

Tags: php, return, usort

I am trying to get PHP to compare two values and sort them using `usort()`. I have this function, which works, however this function stops running if `$a == $b`,

Having this function stop running prevents further functions in the PHP file to run.

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[4] == $b[4]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[4] < $b[4]) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($participants_times,"cmp");
?>
```

When there are two values that are equal, I don't mind which one is in front of the other. I have tried setting `return -1`, `return 0`, and `return 1` when `$a == $b` but they didnt work for me.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what do you mean `stop running`? Is there any errors?

Comment: I have some php that runs after this function and it fails to run at all when there are values that are equal. I have `var_dump()`'d and I know this function is the issue, I don't know how to get retrieve errors from this function though.

Comment: can you add the var_dump of $a and $b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace ternary operator with nested if-else statements. In your condition, it returns 1 for both `>` and `==` comparison.

```
if ($a[4] < $b[4])
    return -1;
else if ($a[4] > $b[4]) 
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

Comment: Sorry Asking a silly question in old thread But you are saying it returns 1 for both > and == comparison . how ? it is not returning 1 for == comparison it returning 0. if == comparison pass it wont go to the next line of comparison

Answer (score 0):

because you don't care the equal case, just ignore it

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return ($a[4] < $b[4]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($participants_times,"cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answers provided are very likely correct to my question - however, in my case, the issue was related to the form of my `function()`'s where I had a function inside a function and a second iteration of the initial function failed.

Moving my `cmp()` function outside of the function that calls it solved my issue.